# Laptop with TV via Mini DP: display settings lost - reverts to mirrored at random

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, nvidia-prime, displayport

**Background:**

I have a Lenovo T530 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.  I use it on my TV, which is connected via the mini DP connection with a mini DP to HDMI cable.

This laptop appears to be using Nvidia Optimus, meaning that in earlier versions of Ubuntu, it would've been handled by [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Since Bumblebee is no longer used, it's now handled by nvidia-prime (which appeared to be installed already for me).

**Problem:**

I will configure the settings in the Displays dialog how I want it (tv set to 1080p, built-in display set to its own native resolution), and it works just how you'd expect for a while.

I can't figure out the pattern; it seems random, but **the system will revert itself to a mirrored setup**, with both displays changing to a non-native resolution.

It happens probably twice a day.

This happens with both the nouveau driver and the nvidia proprietary driver.

**Main Question:**

Are there any logs I can check to see why the display settings would revert?  Or other methods of debugging display settings issues?

Thank you.

**Follow up:**

It seemed a little more stable when I set the resolutions through the nvidia settings dialog, but then a few hours later, it reverted itself to mirrored again with the TV going to a lower resolution.